# Adding your own properties to tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way I can add my own property to a tabpage? I want to save a value for each tabpage in tabcontrol. Im making a notepad and I want to store the path of the document because when i change documents it will go? Is there anywhere permanently I can save it

Example is

```
//Only as a example

tabControl1.Controls[0].MyPropertyHere = MyPropertyText;
//Or even better bellow..
tabControl1.SelectedTab.MyPropertyHere = MyPropertyText;
```

Comment: You could easily create a custom tabcontrol and add an extra property to it.

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg it is not so easy.  The property needs to be added to a `TabPage`, not the `TabControl`.  Most of the required properties that would need to be changed to create a custom `TabControl` that used custom `TabPages` are private or internal, which means this approach would require re-writing a new `TabControl`, probably starting from the .NET source.  This is probably not the best solution.  It's probably better to store this information somewhere else in the business logic, writing a wrapper or `UserControl` to tie it into the user interface.

Comment: Casting is required: ((MyTabpage)tabControl.TabPages[0]).MyProperty.  Nothing very pretty.  Problems that disappear when you separate the view from the data.